# Distance from center of circle to point on line segment

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles, convex-hulls

Imagine any two fixed points $A$, $B$ inside a circle, and add a third point $C$ on the line segment $\overline{AB}$.

We may write

$$
\vec{c}=\vec{a}+\mu(\vec{b}-\vec{a})
$$

and name $a$, $b$ and $c=c(\mu)$ the distance of each of those points from the center of the circle.

I'm looking for any simple relation of $c$ in terms of $\mu$ and given $a$ and $b$, because what I could come up with so far does look far more complicated than one might expect, so maybe I'm missing something.

From law of sines:

$$
c = \mu(1-\mu)d\left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\delta_1}+\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\delta_2}\right)
$$

(actually looks quite nice, but $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are dependent of $\mu$).

From law of cosines:

$$
c^2=\tfrac12(d^2\mu^2+d^2(1-\mu)^2+a^2+b^2)-d(a\cos\beta\cdot\mu+b\cos\alpha\cdot(1-\mu))
$$

[image]

Comment: The circle seems irrelevant. It may constrain the positions of $A$ and $B,$ but to actually answer the question you only need to know those positions, not the reason why other positions were not chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$
\vec{c}=\vec{a}+\mu(\vec{b}-\vec{a})=(1-\mu)\vec a +\mu \vec b
$$

Then

$$c^2 = (1-\mu)^2a^2 +\mu^2 b^2 +2\mu(1-\mu)\vec a \cdot \vec b$$